# Ionic PopUp : TypeError: Cannot read property 'confirm' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, ionic-popup

I would like to code a simple "confirm ionic pop up", but I had this issue that I can't solve. I'm sure if you take a look you'll find it out, because now it's like I was totally blind against it ...

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'confirm' of undefined**

Here is my code :

```js
// Here is the start of my "directive.js" file, I have one directive and 3 controllers

var myApp = angular.module('app.directives', [])

myApp.directive('activePageHighlight', ['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state){
  
// Something else
  
}]);

// Here is my controller

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {
  
$scope.info = function(){
    
var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
    // Here I tried to add $scope, but I'm not sure if is it usefull
    scope:$scope,
    title: 'Consume Ice Cream',
    template: '<button class="button button-primary" ng-click="info()">Confirm</button>'
   });

   confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
     if(res) {
       console.log('You are sure');
     } else {
       console.log('You are not sure');
     }
   });
 };

}]);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  
    <button ng-click="info()" class="calm button-block">Info 1</button>
  
</div>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {
```

You forgot to inject the `$ionicPopup` and `$timeout` service:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicPopup', '$timeout', function ($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only injecting `$scope` as dependency for your controller, add the rest too and it should work.

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicPopup', '$timeout', function ($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout) { 
// ... 
}])
```

Comment: Thanks to you too ! :)